# Ubuntu 20.04 Read only USB

Tags: usb, 20.04, read-only

I have an USB of 8 GB, it is somehow set to read only, previously it was working fine, but I think there is some virus or something that has turned it into a readonly system. I just want to remove everything from it and add other things. How can i do it?

I do not have much knowledge, so you can tell me and I will put the output of commands that will help you diagnose the problem.

I have tried a lot of solutions on stack overflow and ask ubuntu but no use

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/250286/how-to-change-read-only-pendrive
All solutions from above link

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216152/usb-disk-read-only-cannot-format-turn-off-write-protection
Most solutions from this link

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216338/430142 this answer sets read only to 0, but in actually the disk is read only so can not do anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB devices showing as read only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563764/usb-devices-showing-as-read-only) and [How to restore original size and unboot my bootable USB pendrive](https://askubuntu.com/q/496309/)

Answer (score 0):

You USB drive is write protected.

You may find a small tab on the side of the device which you have perhaps inadvertently moved to set it to the locked position. Change the position of the slider to unlock it.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, USB does not have anything like this.