# How Do I Fix SanDisk USB mounted in Read-Only Mode?

Tags: usb, mount

I have a SanDisk Cruzer 32GB USB which houses my Ubuntu GNOME 14.10 OS. Today I tried booting up my machine and I received errors about buffer I/O or something to that effect. I ignored it and booted into my OS. Upon logging-in, my system was lagging and unresponsive at time. I took it to Live Mode with a the Same 14.10 and in disks, I realized that the system was in read-only mode. I tried formatting via disks and gparted but I receive the error or filesystem mounted in read-only mode.

How do I go about solving this issue?

Here is my dmesg output related to the USB;

```
[ 8514.197234] usb 7-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 8514.327982] usb 7-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5571
[ 8514.327991] usb 7-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 8514.327996] usb 7-1: Product: Cruzer Fit
[ 8514.328000] usb 7-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 8514.328004] usb 7-1: SerialNumber: 4C530302740119120562
[ 8514.329089] usb-storage 7-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 8514.329312] scsi7 : usb-storage 7-1:1.0
[ 8515.330771] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Fit       1.26 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 8515.331629] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 8515.332659] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 62530624 512-byte logical blocks: (32.0 GB/29.8 GiB)
[ 8515.336658] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is on
[ 8515.336667] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 80 00
[ 8515.337325] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 8515.372115]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4 sdb5
[ 8515.377850] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
ubuntu-gnome@ubuntu-gnome:~$`
```

Comment: Does your Sandisk has your write protection? Looks like your sandisk does: "Write Protect is on", so try switching your protection off.

Comment: @mikewhatever How do I do that? If it's hardware related, [this is what my USB looks like](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pSsrW1vGL._SY300_.jpg).

Comment: @mikewhatever I tried all the [methods outlined here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/101637/usb-turn-write-protection-off) no luck.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue/Limitation in SANdisk where it is designed with Write Protect is on. Check the  speller's post in the link given below

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121061/disk-on-key-is-read-only-on-every-computer

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Mine got locked for weeks on Read-Only mode. I tried everything I could find online both on Ubuntu and Windows. Finally it was fixed simply with "Disks" software that comes with Ubuntu 15.10.
- Plug your USB (mine is 8GB SanDisk Cruzer Fit).
- Open "Disks", select the drive, then unmount it.
- From the Settings menu select format partition, and format it as NTFS.

Few days in, it's still working fine on different machines and OS.

Good luck!

Comment: For the record, I tried formatting before on Ubuntu and Windows. I also tried USB repair tools.. nothing worked before.

Answer (score 0):

On a MBP (not Linux) I managed to make it rw again, by first un-mounting it (I did that within diskutility, to have more direct visibility), and then in a terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /Volumes/TheName && sudo mount -w -t msdos /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/TheName
```

(adapt that to the target at hand, like -t exfat, etc.)