# Why is my flash drive generating .lnk files? How did my flash drive become write protected when I never put that setting?

Tags: usb, flash

I'm honestly not sure what went wrong with my flash drive. My flash drive doesn't store any of the actual files that I save. Instead, it stores the .lnk files. Now when I use a computer at a local library, it won't let me open it because it's a shortcut. What do I do? Not just that, but my flash drive won't let me do any changes because it somehow became write protected. I now can't flush my flash drive. What do I do? HELP!

Comment: LNK is a file extension for a short cut file used by Microsoft Windows to point to an executable file. Are you trying to open these on an Ubuntu machine in your library? you haven't given enough details.As for the write protection http://askubuntu.com/questions/101637/usb-turn-write-protection-off

Comment: @damien Hi. I don't know what an Ubuntu machine is. Additionally, I don't know how to access that screen for the write protection. Thx for your help though.

Comment: @JimmyThaiTea the fact that you have mentioned that you don't know what Ubuntu machine is ( a computer with Ubuntu  Linux as operating system ) , means you came to this site asking a question about general computing. This site is strictly for Ubuntu-related questions.