# Write protection can't be turned off

Tags: usb, format, read-only, micro-sd

I want to format my microSD card, but when I try an error says that the file system is read-only. I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101637/usb-turn-write-protection-off), but none of the answers work form my case, which is identical to the one I linked to. Any helpful suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible your SD card may be corrupted. If it's not and you're using an SD adapter, there's a little switch that you have to toggle to disable write protection. If that doesn't work, 99% of the time, it mean your sd card is corrupted.

Comment: Thanks, @ tatakai-wasumi. I tried everything I could think of and nothing worked. The card appears to be corrupted.