# Unable to remove write protection from pen drive

Tags: permissions, usb-drive

I have scandisk 16GB pendrive which accidentally got write protected(s/w as there is no hardware write protection feature availiable).

I have tried **sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb1** still it is write protected.

What other ways availiable to remove the write protection?

Comment: Does `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb1 /mountpoint` not work? What does `dmesg` say? `journalctl -e`?

Comment: There can be different problems, that make the drive read-only. You can try according to the following link (try first the options in the list "The drive is read-only ..."), https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035 ; You can also try to mount the drive manually according to the following link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072

Comment: @waltinator   : I have tried mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb1 /mountpoint and dmesg  log :
 Direct-Access     SanDisk    1.26 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 1795.509415] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 1795.510302] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 31266816 512-byte logical blocks: (16.0 GB/14.9 GiB)
[ 1795.511158] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is on
[ 1795.511169] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 80 00
[ 1795.511442] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 1795.523481]  sdb: sdb1
[ 1795.525272] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk

Comment: Am I facing this issue:   http://forums.sandisk.com/t5/All-SanDisk-USB-Flash-Drives/SanDisk-Cruzer-Blade-16GB-write-protected-error/td-p/253484/page/7

Comment: Maybe you are facing that issue. But you should try first according to the list in my previous comment before giving up on the drive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer by Angel Genchev: [USB turn write protection off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101637/usb-turn-write-protection-off)

> To turn off disk device`s write protect, we use the low level system
>   utility hdparm like this:
>
> ```
> sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb
> ```
>
> where we asume that /dev/sdb is the Physical disk device we're working
>   on. If the device has partitions that are mounted as read-only, you
>   should re-mount 'em as read-write in order to write data to them.
>
> Hope that helps.

You should run `sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb` rather than `sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb1`. So run your command but without the 1 at the end. You specify the device itself as a whole and not the partition number.

Comment: I have tried :  **sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb** but it didn't help.