# Cannot delete a tar.bz2 file from pendrive

Tags: command-line, permissions, tar

I want to delete a tar.bz2 file from my pendrive. I tried shift+delete, but nothing happened. Then in terminal I tried sudo rm command, I got the following error -

rm: cannot remove `avi.tar.bz2': Read-only file system

I tried sudo chmod 777, but the output is -

chmod: changing permissions of `avi.tar.bz2': Read-only file system

I am not able to remove the tar.bz.2 file. Any help?

Comment: The filesystem itself is read-only, it can happen for number of reasons.

Comment: Check if `mount -o rw,remount /dev/sdc` works. `/dev/sdc` is _example_ name of your pendrive.

Comment: So what can I do now, just have a back up and format the pendrive?

Answer (score 1):

you need to mount it in read write mode, since `chmod` is a write operation it will not work.

Check this instructions

[Make Read items RW](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable)

Comment: I could delete the tar.bz2 file using mount -o ... command suggseted by Danatela. Thank you soo much

Comment: @avinash, if you want to say something to me, you should answer below my comment and put `@` sign before my name. Now RayOfCommand got your message :)