# I can not write on and delete from my phone connected via usb

Tags: usb, mount, permissions, read-only

I have checked out this question [How to make read-only file system writable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable) but I still have the problem.

My option is 'rw', but it does not help, I still can not write files and delete

```
mount| grep 0001-E856
/dev/sdc1 on /media/0001-E856 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks)
```

Other options:
Phone is Nokia x2-02, connected via mini usb cable and with a micro SD card.

Answer (score 0):

What's the output of: `ls -lh /media/0001-E856`

Look at the 3rd & 4th column, maybe ownership is given to root only.

Comment: o great :DD i'm so dumb, didn't try with root after remounting!
thank you :]

Comment: but the answer was not, all the permissions are given to the user i was logged in with and root stopped working after copying the first file