# How to install Ubuntu on a USB drive without it being a Read-Only filesystem?

Tags: boot, usb, mount, permissions

After my MacBook stopped working yesterday I have been trying to get it to work again, but right now it won't boot as there seem to be problems with the SSD. The support recommended booting into my MacBook using a USB-installation of an OS, so that I could back up my files, after which I would have to perform a reset. I used a USB-boot of Ubuntu to try to access my files. After booting I tried to navigate to my user files on the Mac's SSD, but I didn't have the permissions to access some directories. I tried to use `sudo chmod 755 Documents/`, but I received the message:

> chmod: changing permissions of 'Documents/': Read-only file system

So then I checked [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable), but can't get the solution to work, if I try to use the `sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/ubuntu'` or `sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/ubuntu/Macintosh\ HD'`  I get the message:

> mount: can't find /media/ubuntu in etc/fstab or /etc/mtab

I am unsure what to try next at this point, so I hope that one of you could help me out.

Comment: My Macs file system, hfs+, only has read support, which should be sufficient to copy files. I don't think linux permissions work there as well. You should probably use another my mac for write access.

Answer (score 0):

Write support for HFS+ in Linux is very experimental and disabled by default. You cannot write (that includes permission changes) to such a file system without jumping through some hoops and risking the integrity of your data, but I you don't need to either to perform a backup.

Since the files on the OS X file system belong to another user as the default user on the Ubuntu live system, you probably need to access them as super user. To start Nautilus, the default file manager, as super user, open a terminal window and run:

```
gksudo nautilus
```