# How to make read-only file system writable on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, filesystem, read-only

I am trying to delete some files from my microSD card on my Ubuntu 16.04 (I am using MircoSD adapter in order to access my files). However the file system has been changed to 'read-only' and hence I can't delete the files in it.

I tried remounting it read-write (after I read it from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable)):

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/tuxication/MyDrive'
```

But it says:

```
mount: cannot remount rw read-write, is write-protected
```

I tried the other methods mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable) but none seems to work.

Just to aid you with further details, if I want to format the microSD, it says:

```
Error wiping device: Command-line `wipefs -a "/dev/mmcblk0p1"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: 
 wipefs: error: /dev/mmcblk0p1: probing initialization failed: Read-only file system
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Any idea how I might solve this?

Comment: Does your memory card have any tiny hardware switch which turns on write protection?

Comment: Many adapters have a plastic switch that makes the card read only. If there is one, try to toggle it.

Comment: And if there isn't a switch, then the adapter is more than likely bad.  Try a different adapter or get an all-in-one memory card reader.

Comment: @ByteCommander it does. I did unlock it before use.

Comment: @Terrance I don't own a all-in-one memory card reader. But I could purchase one though. Are you sure the problem is hardware related?

Comment: Every time it has happened to me it was because the adapter went bad.  Most of those adapters are really cheaply made.  I would determine if it was indeed a hardware issue by plugging it into another computer and verify it was read only.

Comment: What make & model of computer, SD card reader and the SD card?

Comment: Can you read the files OK?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yep I can read the files alright.

Comment: @Terrance Alright so finally this is where things stand. I removed the adapter and plugged into my Windows machine, it works perfectly fine and I can delete files from there with ease. So perhaps I might not need to change the file system anymore. However, I would still like to know the solution, if available.

Comment: Good that your adapter is still good.  I am wondering if it works more easily in the all-in-one memory card reader is because that runs on the USB bus, but I am not sure what bus the SD card runs on.   I have read where people are saying that it is dangerous and wrong to add your user to the `disk` group, but myself I have not had an issue with it.  I guess you could try it and see.  The command to add yourself to it is `sudo usermod -a -G disk <username>`

Comment: Rather than mounting the adapter w/card yourself have you thought of just plugging it in, opening Nautilus and let it mount it? I do that with external drives and smartphones without any extra work on my part. It's worth a shot.

Comment: Try to change disk permission, with "chown" and "chmod": `chown USER:USER -R /dev/mmcblk0p1 && chmod 777 -R /dev/mmcblk0p1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
umount /dev/mmcblk0p1
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0p1 bs=1024
mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/mmcblk0p1 -I
```

Comment: It says: No command 'unmount' found, did you mean:
 Command 'umount' from package 'mount' (main)
unmount: command not found