# Internal drive says read only file system

Tags: hard-drive

I have an internal hard drive formatted as NTFS as a shared storage space between Linux and Microsoft with a duel boot setup, but Linux says is a read only file system and refuses to let me use it.

Being root makes no difference. I can read the contents, but nothing else.

[image: screenshot of error "The group could not be changed" error]

Comment: For me restarting the system has solved the issue.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version and desktop environment?

Comment: How did you mount the drive? Had the same issue once upon a time, and cannot remember what exactly what was the cause but they way I had mounted it was wrong. If you unmount it, then mount it by editing `/etc/fstab` your problems should hopefully resolve.

Comment: Related: [How to make read-only file system writable?](https://askubuntu.com/q/47538/816190)