# Why my second disk is read-only?

Tags: mount, kubuntu, filesystem, disk, read-only

Can you help me? My problem is:

I wanted to make a folder on my second disk, in Windows marked as D:, but it's impossible. How to make this disk writable on my Kubuntu? If this is a terminal command, how to do this automatically at startup?

Thanks for help,

lucasio

Comment: It might be readonly of you didn't "shut windows down".  Clicking shutdown on windows 10 does not shutdown unless you hold the shift key whilst you click it!  It hibernates or saves its state to disk which means that the D: is locked by windows.  Windows Restart performs a proper shutdown too

Comment: Wha? Thx for help, but I did it. I typed: sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1 and it helped. Sorry for sh*tpost.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make read-only file system writable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable)

Answer (score 1):

just like SEWTGIYWTKHNTDS said above you can
fully shutdown your windows by restarting,
pressing **SHIFT**  + click shutdown in Start Menu,
or using this command in admin command prompt

```
shutdown /s /f /t 0
```

and you can uncheck the option Turn on fast startup in settings