# Additional harddrive only in read mode

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab

I have additional HDD:

```
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
...
# External 1TB drive for some data
/dev/disk/by-uuid/20A949F121CEADD8 /mnt/20A949F121CEADD8 auto rw,acl 0 0
```

but its always mounted in read only mode..

Partition type of this HDD is NTFS.

```
uname -a
Linux My-Tower 5.14.0-1052-oem #59-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 9 09:37:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I tried from other SO but:

```
sudo mount -o rw,users,umask=000,exec /dev/sdc1 /mnt/hdd_data
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
```

what can I do to change it for normal usage?

thanks

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details, but have you checked system logs for issues that will cause a RW mount to *flip* to RO?  You also didn't provide us with any clues as to what sort of *file-system* you're trying to mount.

Comment: You've added kernel details but still not OS/release details (it's an OEM kernel which would require more specific details about your hardware for us to interpret the results into your *unstated* Ubuntu product/release details, so why not tell us?)  Have you explored system logs for clues?  (*Its the first place I'd look, and I still don't know what OS/product/release details though I now know you're using an OEM kernel on that unstated release*)

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072) to an answer [to another question] at AskUbuntu may help you solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make read-only file system writable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable)

Comment: You've still not provided any OS/release details; but you've highlighted it's NTFS and also it's in an *unclean* state, thus any attempt to mount it RW is automatically *flipped* to RO to prevent dataloss.  Close the file-system making it clean (on the machine that has left it *unclean*), then you can mount it RW (ie. turn off hibernation etc. which include fastboot on windows which is just a form of hibernation; fastboot resumes from a hibernate file created during upgrades).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/11840/)

Answer (score 2):

ok thanks guys for help!

I found here how to mount it properly:
[How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072)
then I realized about NTFS issues so I did fix:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdc1
```

and its ok now :)

Comment: That can be a dangerous fix; it'll allow you to mount it RW on a GNU/Linux system like Ubuntu, but can create problems if that drive is later used on a windows system that believes that system is currently *hibernated*, ie. it may ignore any changes working from the image it stored of what the file-system was like before the machine entered the hibernate/off mode.   *Ensure your backups of data on that drive are up-to-date first!  and don't forget the corruption may take time before its noticed if the cause was hibernate/fastboot*

Comment: @guiverc thanks but that Issue was due to that in the past there was some Windows there, not I keep on this HDD only data. So no problem at all :)

Comment: I had the same issue. .In my case, I just needed to shutdown windows properly.